# How to get month and year from date in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to get month and year data in `Nodejs` and query to insert into database?

Comment: Why would you tag this with php sql and psql?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? This question is far too broad for this platform.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and show us some code so we can help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var months = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "july", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"];

var date = new Date();
var month = date.getMonth(); // returns 0 - 11

var year = date.getFullYear();

console.log(months[month]);

console.log(year);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the current month and year you can do the following

```
var date= new Date();
var month = date.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
var year = date.getUTCFullYear();
```

However i cannot answer on how to save to Database since that depends entirely on the Database and Object Modelling you are using. Can you provide more info on the Database please.
Thanks.

Comment: Please avoid answering questions which doesn't even show their research effort. It is like doing someone else's work and making them lazy.